# Find Regions associated with a line

Tags: c, linux, math, geometry

Assume that I have a rectangular regions. On this rectangular region, I can draw Vertical and Horizontal Lines. Each of these lines creates small rectangular regions that are associated with the line ( In other words, the line serves as the border for the small rectangular region). Let is number these regions as 1,2,3 etc..

My question is this: For any given line ( Vertical or Horizontal ), how does one find the regions ( or region numbers) associated ( touches or borders) with this line. What would be the simplest algorithm to determine this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you asking this for the case of drawing lots of lines (and every time you draw a line, you end up with more smaller rectangles)? I suspect you want to create a linked list from a line to each rectangle, and update the list every time you bisect a bunch of rectangles. Make a second list of rectangles to lines as well, so you know which lines to update. In this way you end up with a double-linked index so you can go from line to region, and from region to line. Does that sound like a workable direction to you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Using a linklist to associate a line to a region is fine.But how do you find the regions associated with a line, without resorting to finding the intersection between lines and regions or so? Assume that when you start, you are aware of the number of rows and columns created. How would you go about picking up each line and finding out the regions associates and update that linklist?

Comment: What would be the easiest way without resorting to finding bisection points or so?

Comment: Because you have a rectangular grid, all rectangles that have "left < x && right > x" will spawn two more rectangles. I don't see a way around doing that - although if you stay with the tree approach, if you remember the "history" of regions (which are the result of bisection of two regions) then you can start from the root, and stop looking for bisected regions if the parent is not bisected. That means you will typically search just a small subset of the regions - important when their number becomes very large.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer from what I understood (your question is a bit vague):

Can't you represent your regions with `matrix[horizontal][vertical]` ?
Then a line is represented by an index either horizontal or vertical and you end up manipulating indexes rather than bigger structures:

For example: Line `horizontal = 2` generates regions with index x s.t. `UPPER_BOUND > x > 2`